# Testing for Non Linearity. What now?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, lm

I'm a junior Business Intelligence Analyst at a retail company in Latin America.

I was asked to deploy a prediction model by hour that can predict how many transactions each restaurant will get each hour.
Obviously this varies by day of the week, month, etc. It also varies by store but right now the model is a pooled model (I realize that a per store model might be an improvement and I've done testing and in some stores the accuracy improves but not significantly)

My solution (that's already implemented) was a linear regression model that uses as independent variables:

- Same hour and same weekday from 14 days before
- Same hour and same weekday from 21 days before
- Same hour and same weekday from 28 days before
- Same hour and same weekday from 364 days before (Equivalent day from last year)

Here are the regression results:
[image]

The model is working fine and the results are decent but I would like them to improve significantly. I have joined various R and stats courses for this and read several books and I started testing for non-linearity (I know I should have done this before). I did not do exploratory data analysis before concluding that the relationship was linear and I realize now this was a mistake.

Now I ran residual tests among others and I notice the data does not fit the assumptions done by a linear regression model.

Here is the image from the test:
[image: Residual and Q-Q test]

I'm looking for any tips on how to further test the data and improve the results. It doesn't necessarily have to be with a regression. I've tested some interaction effects (multiplying the independent variables among them and including those products as variables) and the results did not improve.

Let me know what you think.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Start searching for information related to ARIMA (autoregressive integrated moving average) and time-series analysis. The `forecasting` package in `R` may be helpful. OLS is the wrong technique to be using here.

Comment: @HFBrowning Caveat: OLS *can* be used for co-integrating regression/error correction model approaches to autoregression.